# Using a UNC path with Classic ASP FileSystemObject

Tags: asp-classic

According to the websites I could find the below code should work.  If I change the path to C:\whats_new.txt  it works just fine.

```
Const Filename = "\\SCPAFS1PW\returns\whats_new.txt"    ' file to read
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

' Create a filesystem object
Dim FSO
set FSO = server.createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Map the logical path to the physical system path
Dim Filepath
Filepath = Filename

if FSO.FileExists(Filepath) Then <--This always returns false
```

Comment: Define "fails".  Is there an error message, or does it just not find the file?

Comment: No, this is classic asp remember....haha.  No run time error, FSO.FileExists(Filepath) always returns false.  I found the issue and posted my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system reports the file does not exist.  In fact it was actually a permissions issue.  Microsoft designed the error so that if you do not have permission you cannot fish to figure out file names on a folder.

I modified my permisions to the directory and I was able to access it using a UNC path.

Comment: What Permissions did you give to the directory?

Comment: @doug-chamberlain Can you please tell us what permissions worked for you?

Comment: Argh it kills me when people post "answer/not answer"s like this.  How hard would it have been to give a little detail so folks down the road would actually see a solution?

Answer (score 0):

asp Classic does not (by default) use the Application Pool id for authentication - 
To set the username for iis follow these steps:
on IIS select the website / application you wish to change:
Double Click on Authentication
Click on Anonymous Authentication and then click edit
You can either set a specific user or select the Application pool identity